# I have a careers account but it doesn't show up in my SO profile

Tags: support

On the profile page there's this textfield with a link to your careers profile: "Stack Overflow Careers Profile".

In my case, though, this is empty, and shows a link next to it with the text "Discover Stack Overflow Careers". But I *do* have a careers profile. It's for the same StackExchange account as my StackOverflow profile.

Why is this so? How can I change this?

**Edit**: Within the Applications tab Stack Overflow Careers is listed as one of the applications that I have authorized to use this account.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on 'discover stack overflow careers' it will give you the option to display it on your profile